# How do I prevent people from joining my Minigames Server?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

So there's these certain people that I always run into on my Minigames servers, (they're all modders) and they ruin the game for me but I can't kick them while we're playing. I tried blocking them but they can still join and I also tried reporting them but I can't do that. Is there any way I can prevent them from joining my servers again?

I'm playing on PS3.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is set their spawn point in the void, or make a 2-tick comparator command block clock that kills them automatically that sets off every time they join using the /testfor command as a trigger.

Comment: Can you do this on the console version of the game...?  [`/testfor`](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/testfor) appears to have only been for the Java version.

Comment: @TimmyJim You can't. I play on the PS3 and there are non of the following: shields, command blocks, cheats, anything past the aquatic update.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the PS3 edition does not support any "server" management. The only way to play is online over the PSN, or over LAN.

Because of this, there is no "[whitelist](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/whitelist)" which is how you would normally manage this.

So aside from [reporting the players](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/get-help/help-library/my-account/parental-controls/how-to-file-a-complaint-against-another-playstation-network-user/), you would only be able to do this via a VPN, or locally over a LAN network.